# External Data (i.e textures), not being found by blender

Tags: texturing

I just got a brand new 2021 MacBook Pro, have the latest version of Blender.
But when I loading an image texture, the object turns pink.
It's not that the textures have worked and are suddenly lost, they are not working initially.
Help is appreciated :)

Comment: So, just to understand this correctly: you have for example an _Image Texture_ node in the _Shader Editor_, click on the _Open_ button, select an image from a folder on your PC, either double-click to open it or use the _Open Image_ button, then the name appears in the node but the object shows pink instead of the texture? And have you set the _Display Mode_ in the open dialogue to _Thumbnail_? Is the image showing there correctly before opening it? And it is happening with all images or just certain ones?

Comment: Hey Gordon, so it actually seems like .jpgs do no work, but I tried with a jpg.webp and that worked with no issues. Is this a thing? Still pretty green to the blender world.

Comment: No, I have lots of textures that are jpgs, never had issues before. Strange... maybe it's a bug? Just tested it (latest stable version), no problems. When you say latest version, you mean the stable version 3.4.1 or do you refer to some experimental build? Because then it's never guaranteed that it works without flaws, and you should file a bug report for it. In the menu _Help_ > _Report a Bug_. Same goes for the stable version of course, because it seems like a bug and not normal behaviour.